# Scraping Paginated Pages using Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have got my scraper working, it pulls the correct data from all 9 pages on the site. The one issue I have though is I believe  the method I am currently using is not ideal (in a case where there was to be a page number greater than the range I have entered, then those results will be missed).

My code is below:

```
import requests
import time
import csv
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

houses = []

url = "https://www.propertypal.com/property-to-rent/newtownabbey/"
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")
g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "propbox-details"})
for item in g_data:
    try:
        title = item.find_all("span", {"class": "propbox-addr"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        town = item.find_all("span", {"class": "propbox-town"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        price = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price-value"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    try:
        period = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price-period"})[0].text
    except:
        pass
    course=[title,town,price,period]
    houses.append(course)


for i in range(1,15):
    time.sleep(2)#delay time requests are sent so we don't get kicked by server
    url2 = "https://www.propertypal.com/property-to-rent/newtownabbey/page-{0}".format(i)
    page2=requests.get(url2)
    print(url2)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page2.text,"lxml")
    g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "propbox-details"})
    for item in g_data:
        try:
            title = item.find_all("span", {"class": "propbox-addr"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            town = item.find_all("span", {"class": "propbox-town"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            price = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price-value"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            period = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price-period"})[0].text
        except:
            pass

        course=[title,town,price,period]
        houses.append(course)


with open ('newtownabbeyrentalproperties.csv','w') as file:
   writer=csv.writer(file)
   writer.writerow(['Address','Town', 'Price', 'Period'])
   for row in houses:
      writer.writerow(row)
```

As you can see from the code I am using

```
for i in range(1,15):
    time.sleep(2)#delay time requests are sent so we don't get kicked by server
    url2 = "https://www.propertypal.com/property-to-rent/newtownabbey/page-{0}".format(i)
```

to add number 1 through to 14 into the &page= parameter.

This is not ideal as if the site was to have an extra number of pages, such as pages 15,16,17, then the scraper will miss the data on these pages as it will only look at page 14 maximum for data.

Could someone offer assitance into how I could either using pagination to find the number of pages on the webpage to scrape, or a better way to set up this for loop?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Could you try using a while loop with the http status of the request as the flag? Keep looping through pages until http status is 404 (or http status is not 200)

Comment: Or just check if the button for the next page exists...

Comment: @Primoz Could you give me an example of how I could implement this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (I did not test this, it may work or not, just wanted to show the principle)

```
button_next = soup.find("a", {"class": "btn paging-next"}, href=True)
while button_next:
    time.sleep(2)#delay time requests are sent so we don\'t get kicked by server
    url2 = "https://www.propertypal.com{0}".format(button_next["href"])
    page2=requests.get(url2)
    print(url2)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page2.text,"lxml")
    g_data = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "propbox-details"})
    for item in g_data:
        try:
            title = item.find_all("span", {"class": "propbox-addr"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            town = item.find_all("span", {"class": "propbox-town"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            price = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price-value"})[0].text
        except:
            pass
        try:
            period = item.find_all("span", {"class": "price-period"})[0].text
        except:
            pass

    course=[title,town,price,period]
    houses.append(course)

    button_next = soup.find("a", {"class": "btn paging-next"}, href=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

See my modifications below. This solution should be able to continue looping through the pages until it tries to get a page that does not exist. Doing it this way is also beneficial because in your code you will always try 15 pages even if there are only one or two or three, etc.

```
page_num = 0
http_status_okay = True
while http_status_okay:
    page_num = page_num + 1
    time.sleep(2)#delay time requests are sent so we don't get kicked by server
    url2 = "https://www.propertypal.com/property-to-rent/newtownabbey/page-{0}".format(i)
    page2=requests.get(url2)

    # continue if we get a 200 response code
    if page2.status_code is 200:
        http_status_okay = True
    else:
        http_status_okay = False
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I will try this when I get home. One question. When an incorrect page is visit, eg. Page-999 it doesn't display a 404 message or an errors via web browser, it just says on the Property Pal site "You have gone past the last page of the results for this search.

Go back to the last page or the first page of the results". I am guessing that as this site is still giving a HTTP 200 code when a wrong page number is entered that the code above will still think incorrect pages are correct and will try scraping them?

Comment: That is true, yes. Looking closer at the results page I think you are scraping, I see a span: <span class="pgheader-currentpage">Page 2 of 9 (<em>88</em> properties)</span> I wonder if you could grab the number of pages from this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a request to a page which is not exist. For example: https://www.propertypal.com/property-to-rent/newtownabbey/page-999999
Find a difference between pages that are exist and not exist.
Parse next pages until you find this difference.

Comment: Could you provide some example code to show how I could implement this? Thanks

Comment: page-9999 has a message "You have gone past the last page of the results for this search." Which tells that there is no more pages. You can check a status code additionally. I see it sends 404 for pages out of range.